# Solving a particular system in three variables

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

I am trying to analytically solve these equations for the three variables of $\theta$, $L_p$, and $R_c$. Matlab can not solve them! I am wondering if there is any solution for this at all? And how I can find it?

$$
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
R_c-R_c \cos \theta +L_p \sin \theta &=& \sqrt{X^2+Y^2} \\
R_c \sin \theta +L_p \cos \theta &=& Z \\
R_c &=& \frac{L}{\theta}
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Comment: Likely there is no analytic solution, since $\theta$ occurs both inside and outside transcendental functions here. That doesn't mean you can't do anything analytically with them, though---for example, you could substitute the last equation and then expand a few terms of the remaining equations in Taylor series around $\theta = \theta_0$ to analyze the behavior under small perturbations in $\theta$.

Comment: Perhaps you could retitle your question to include the source of these equations, which would make it easier for people who have a related question to find it later.

Comment: Could you give me numbers for $X,Y,Z,L$ ? I would like to see more. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Travis commented, there is no hope to obtain an analytical solution for this system of equations since $\theta$ appears alone and also involved in trigonometric functions (remember that we do not know the solution of the equation $x=\cos(x)$).

However, we can reduce the system to a single equation in $\theta$. Eliminating $R_c$ and $L_p$ from the first and second equations leads to $$R_c=\frac{\cos (\theta ) \sqrt{X^2+Y^2}-Z \sin (\theta )}{\cos (\theta )-1}$$ $$L_p=\cot \left(\frac{\theta }{2}\right) \sqrt{X^2+Y^2}-Z$$ Using the third equation then leads to $$f(\theta)=\frac{\cos (\theta ) \sqrt{X^2+Y^2}-Z \sin (\theta )}{\cos (\theta )-1}-\frac{L}{\theta}=0$$ in which all terms are known. Solve this last equation for $\theta$ and get $R_c$ and $L_p$ from the solutions.

In any manner, numerical methods, such as Newton, will be required but all of that is doable provided a good look at the graph of the function for getting reasonable estimates of the solution.

If the solutions do not correspond to $\cos (\theta )=1$ or $\theta=0$, it is probable that function $$g(\theta)=\cos (\theta ) \left(\theta  \sqrt{X^2+Y^2}-L\right)+L-\theta  Z \sin (\theta )$$ could be more pleasant.

If by chance, $\theta$ is small, a Taylor expansion of $g(\theta)$ built at $\theta=0$ gives an approximation $$\theta \approx \frac{2 \sqrt{X^2+Y^2}}{2 Z-L}$$